# Cannot execute commands after logging in to server over SSH when IP is generated by linux command

Tags: linux, ssh, grep, ifconfig

If I ssh directly `ssh user@192.168.13.2`, the server behaves as normal and I can execute any number of commands before logging out.

The server IP address is very similar to one defined in my network settings, but with the last octet switched. The below command reads from `ifconfig` and generates the correct IP address.

```
ifconfig Netcon | grep "inet " | printf `awk '{ print $2 }'` | tail -c 1 | ssh -tt user@192.168.13.`tr 12 21`
```

SSH prompts for the server password and logs in, showing the new hostname on my prompt. However, anything I enter does not get executed.

```
Last login: Fri Feb 28 09:07:38 2020 from 192.168.13.2
user@192.168.13.2:~$ ping google.com


cd
asdasdwjawdi
```

If I remove the `-tt` from the SSH call, the login fails with:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Comment: Your shell is not connected to stdin of the ssh process because you pipe into it. Use your pipeline to create a variable containing the IP address, then in a second command run `ssh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up *stdin* for the `ssh` command and the processing required to generate the final octet. Essentially your command is in this shape,

```
echo 1.2.3.4 | ssh -tt user@`tr 12 21`
```

From this I hope you can see that the `tr` is receiving input from the `echo` command (your pipeline) so isn't connected to your terminal. Furthermore the `ssh` is also trying to read its input from the pipe.

I think what you probably want is this,

```
ip=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet / { split($2, ip, /\./); printf "%d.%d.%d.2\n", ip[1], ip[2], ip[3] }')
ssh "user@$ip"
```

or on the one line without a temporary variable,

```
ssh "user@$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet / { split($2, ip, /\./); printf "%d.%d.%d.2\n", ip[1], ip[2], ip[3] }')"
```

Comment: Most `ifconfig` commands can be told directly to limit their outputs to one particular address family.  `ifconfig eth0 inet` for example.  One still has to filter a bit, though.  Your `/inet /` match is not word-anchored.  And you have a copy and paste error in the one-line version.

Comment: @JdeBP thanks - on both counts. I get no output for `ifconfig eth0 inet` (a valid interface using IPv4) and no error either.